# OCaml linking error: cannot find crtbegin.o

Tags: ocaml

I installed OCaml on Windows XP using OCPWin a couple of minutes ago. When I tried to compile an [example program](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/languages/ray_tracer/comparison.html), I got two errors:

```
ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find crtend.o: No such file or directory
** Fatal error: Error during linking

File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
```

I can find gcc, ar and ld in the `bin` folder, but `crtbegin.o` or `crtend.o` are not present in the installation directory or its subdirectories. How to resolve this problem? Did I miss something in the (post) installation step?